# Como manipular un elemento seleccionado en select2

Tags: javascript, jquery, select2

Tengo este código y me gustaría saber cómo guardar los datos seleccionados en una variable para manipularlos como json.

Ya he logrado crear los valores a través de datos json.

```js
function customMatcher(params, data) {
   //show childs if search with parent
          data.parentText = data.parentText || "";
          if ($.trim(params.term) === '') {
              return data;
          }


          if (data.children && data.children.length > 0) {
              var match = $.extend(true, {}, data);

              for (var c = data.children.length - 1; c >= 0; c--) {
                  var child = data.children[c];
                  child.parentText += data.parentText + data.text;

                  var matches = customMatcher(params, child);

                  if (matches == null) {
                      match.children.splice(c, 1);
                  }
              }

              if (match.children.length > 0) {
                  return match;
              }

              return customMatcher(params, match);
          }

          var original = (data.parentText + ' ' + data.text).toUpperCase();
          var term = params.term.toUpperCase();

          if (original.indexOf(term) > -1) {
              return data;
          }

          return null;
      }
     
  $("#multisearch").select2({
    language: "es",
    closeOnSelect: false,
    matcher: customMatcher,
    placeholder: "Comienza tu búsqueda",
    data: [{
        id: 0,
        text: 'Linea 1',
        children: [{
            id: 1,
            text: 'San Pablo'
          },
          {
            id: 2,
            text: 'Pajaritos'

          },
          {
            id: 3,
            text: 'Las Rejas'
          },
          {
            id: 4,
            text: 'Ecuador'
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        id: 5,
        text: 'Linea 2',
        children: [{
            id: 6,
            text: 'La Cisterna'
          },
          {
            id: 7,
            text: 'El Parrón'

          },
          {
            id: 8,
            text: 'Lo Ovalle'
          },
          {
            id: 9,
            text: 'Ciudad del niño'
          },
          {
            id: 10,
            text: 'Pajaritos'
          }
        ]
      },

    ]
  });
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js"></script>
 <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<select multiple id="multisearch" style="width:500px">
  </select>
```

Deseo poder capturar los valores seleccionados y almacenarlos en una variable con sus datos JSON

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buenas tienes que tratar el select como a cualquier otro.

Para obtener los datos usa la function `val()` de **Jquery**

```
 $("#multisearch").val()
```

Espero te ayude saludos

---

Para obtener el valor del texto de cada item seleccionado usamos la función `each()` para iterar cada uno de los valores y agregarlos a un array en el que vamos a combinar el valor con el texto

Espero sea lo que buscas amigo

```js
$("#obtenerDatos").click(function(){
  //console.log($("#multisearch").val())
  var arrayValor = $("#multisearch").val()
  var arrayNombres = []
  $(".select2-selection__rendered").find("li").each(function(index){
    
    if($(this).text()!=""){
    var valorAnterior = arrayValor[index]
    arrayValor[index] = {
      id:valorAnterior,
      valor:$(this).text().replace("×","")
    }
    }
    
  })
  
  console.log(arrayValor)
})

function customMatcher(params, data) {
   //show childs if search with parent
          data.parentText = data.parentText || "";
          if ($.trim(params.term) === '') {
              return data;
          }


          if (data.children && data.children.length > 0) {
              var match = $.extend(true, {}, data);

              for (var c = data.children.length - 1; c >= 0; c--) {
                  var child = data.children[c];
                  child.parentText += data.parentText + data.text;

                  var matches = customMatcher(params, child);

                  if (matches == null) {
                      match.children.splice(c, 1);
                  }
              }

              if (match.children.length > 0) {
                  return match;
              }

              return customMatcher(params, match);
          }

          var original = (data.parentText + ' ' + data.text).toUpperCase();
          var term = params.term.toUpperCase();

          if (original.indexOf(term) > -1) {
              return data;
          }

          return null;
      }
     
  $("#multisearch").select2({
    language: "es",
    closeOnSelect: false,
    matcher: customMatcher,
    placeholder: "Comienza tu búsqueda",
    data: [{
        id: 0,
        text: 'Linea 1',
        children: [{
            id: 1,
            text: 'San Pablo'
          },
          {
            id: 2,
            text: 'Pajaritos'

          },
          {
            id: 3,
            text: 'Las Rejas'
          },
          {
            id: 4,
            text: 'Ecuador'
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        id: 5,
        text: 'Linea 2',
        children: [{
            id: 6,
            text: 'La Cisterna'
          },
          {
            id: 7,
            text: 'El Parrón'

          },
          {
            id: 8,
            text: 'Lo Ovalle'
          },
          {
            id: 9,
            text: 'Ciudad del niño'
          },
          {
            id: 10,
            text: 'Pajaritos'
          }
        ]
      },

    ]
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.js"></script>
 <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<select multiple id="multisearch" style="width:500px"  >
  </select>
    
      <button id="obtenerDatos" type="button" name="button">Obtener datos del select</button>
```

Comment: Solo una última duda amigo.

Al obtener los datos, solo está mostrando el id de cada valor seleccionado.

Me gustaría poder mostrar su id, el nombre del padre y el nombre del mismo seleccionado.

Comment: Listo amigo ya te agregue el nombre espero te ayude

Comment: Amigo, disculpa que incomode.

Pero me gustaría saber como junto el id y el valor en un solo array, ya que los muestra en dos array distintos.

Comment: estan en el mismo array el `valor` es el id y el texto es el valor, ya lo cambio

Comment: ya lo cambie para que lo veas mejor

Comment: Me ha funcionado, brutal!! Estaba observando que los valores <optgroup> no pueden ser seleccionables.

¿Los has trabajado de tal manera que al seleccionar el padre, muestre en el select a todos los hijos?

Comment: no amigo la idea es darle la vuelta porque nativamente no tienen la opcion de obtener varios valores entonces es iterar el html y obtener los valores que esten dentro de el espero te ayude y que bueno que te funciones dale como correcta para que los demas programadores sepan saludos

Comment: Perfecto, muchas gracias por todo el apoyo!!

Comment: De nada amigo que bueno poder ayudarte